# How to get column names and and their values to array tuple list with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, c#-5.0

I would like to get "Column Name, Column's Value" in an tuple array list with **entity framework**.

I have this:

```
var colNames = typeof(tbl_ObisSchema).GetProperties().Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
```

to get all column names

```
 using (var dbContext = new db_ReadyEngine_MSSQL())
{
 var colNames = typeof(tbl_ObisSchema).GetProperties().Select(a => a.Name).ToList();

 List<Tuple<string, string>> list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
 list.Add(Tuple.Create(ColumnName, ColumnValue));

}
```

How done it?
Thanks a lot...

Comment: Consider using `KeyValuePair<string, object>` instead. Feels more natural to use than `Tuple<string, object>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column on its own isn't enough; you'll need to read the column values from a specific entity.

Once you have an entity, you can use [the `DbContext.Entry` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) to get the [`DbEntityEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696410%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) instance for that entity. The [`CurrentValues` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696217%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) will then give you access to the current property values for that entity.

```
using (var dbContext = new db_ReadyEngine_MSSQL())
{
    var entity = dbContext.Set<tbl_ObisSchema>().Find(thePrimaryKeyToFind);
    if (entity == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Record not found");

    var entry = dbContext.Entry(entity);
    var currentPropertyValues = entry.CurrentValues;

    List<Tuple<string, object>> list = currentPropertyValues.PropertyNames
        .Select(name => Tuple.Create(name, currentPropertyValues[name]))
        .ToList();

    // Do something with the list...
}
```